# Typeahead not Populating the data Source

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js

```
<div class="well">  
<input type="text" class="span3" style="margin: 0 auto;" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="4" data-source="["Ahmedabad","Akola","Asansol","Aurangabad","Bangaluru","Baroda","Belgaon","Berhumpur","Calicut","Chennai","Chapra","Cherapunji"]">  
</div>
```

I have added the data-source inline.

Check this fiddle Link : http://jsfiddle.net/5WjHR/

It is not auto completing the data in the input box.

The Typeahead JS & Bootstrap CSS are added as external resources in the fiddle already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single and double quote combination must be used, or they must be escaped.

```
<input type="text" class="span3" style="margin: 0 auto;" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="4" data-source='["Ahmedabad","Akola","Asansol","Aurangabad","Bangaluru","Baroda","Belgaon","Berhumpur","Calicut","Chennai","Chapra","Cherapunji"]'>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5WjHR/2/

Answer (score 1):

Change data-source double quotes to single and it should work :)

http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/5WjHR/1/

```
data-source='["Ahmedabad","Akola","Asansol","Aurangabad","Bangaluru","Baroda","Belgaon","Berhumpur","Calicut","Chennai","Chapra","Cherapunji"]'
```